# implement a notification view like xcode's "build success" in iPad

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

I don't like the UIAlert from cocoa and want to have some notification that does not require any user interaction, very similar to the "build success/failed" notification from Xcode. Is there anything on the shelf that I can use or what's the best approach to do this myself?

Thanks in advance

Leo

Comment: Those alerts are called 'Bezels' in XCode settings. I don't know of anything which allows that to be programmed, but that might aid your search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You download working source code from GitHub: [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

I'm using it and it works great.

Comment: It seems this one has more features. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [samvermette's Progress HUD](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD). It is highly configurable & customizable, should help you out.